# CodeSense doesn't always work when importing Frameworks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, xcode4.2

When I was using Xcode 3.2 and add an existing framework, the code sense would detect the framework name when I type **`#import <`**.

Say for example I added framework **"MediaPlayer"**. I then type **`#import <Me`** and the code sense would suggest me **`#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`**

Now I am using Xcode 4.2.1, and I noticed this code sense doesn't work quite that well for some frmeworks. (for example "CoreAudio" could be suggested successfully, but "MediaPlayer" and "CoreMotion" can not).

Is there anything wrong with Xcode or am I missing some setting so the code sense doesn't detect these framework?

> **Edited on 27/Feb/2012:** This is confirmed solved in Xcode 4.3
>
> **Edited on 7/Mar/2012:** I thought it was fixed in Xcode 4.3. But strangely, it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.
>
> **Edited on 3/AUG/2012:** This is confirmed solved in Xcode 4.4

Comment: I've noticed this as well. It seems Xcode only indexes the OS X framework folder. So the frameworks that are shared, like CoreAudio or Foundation, get auto-completed. But it also mistakenly auto-completes for Mac-only frameworks like Quartz and Webkit.

Comment: Thanks Wekwa. This makes me feel that there may be a setting somewhere which allows us to define the location of iOS-only frameworks, so that the code sense can detect the framework names.

Comment: Reported to Apple and here is the response:

This is a follow up to Bug ID# 10770620.  After further investigation it has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 7407222.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i was facing several time..
I found one solution... But unable to find what the reason behind it...

In xcode 4.4 and above versions Its works perfectly..
But if you get such problems OR getting errors like....
`#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>  ----Not found file`
Clean your project - rebuild it OR Reopen your xcode window.. I am sure it will work perfectly..